# Xcode do wrong connection to field

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have two fields Postal code and State.

[image]

I added segue to State field:

[image]

But action works for Postal code field. Why ?

Comment: what is the problem that you are having

Comment: segue works for wrong field. i added it to state field, but it works for postal code field

Comment: So remove and redo all the connection again... :)

Comment: i tried... And close xcode too

Comment: and when i add segue to postal field it works for state field... magic...

Comment: :o will you please share your project(if its demo project), it little bit interesting.

Comment: so right click on the object then remove all connections then redo it

Comment: i can't, but let me give you another screenshot: http://storage7.static.itmages.ru/i/15/1106/h_1446838991_7312811_0d8ac4b980.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got the reason**

I create a scenario and fond that when you set segue to text field
It will called when you lost focus

**SO, it is not a bug** i guess

**If you want to navigate on the click on text field** 
Set delegate of text field and write below clode
**Objective-c**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"call" sender:nil];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Simple, Set delegate and called segue on textFieldShouldBeginEditing

Comment: @Arti see update, return NO instead of YES so that keyboard will not appear when you click on text field